# Hide checked element Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have three arrays, and i every item has the checkbox. I need to hide each checked element

```
<ul class="list" v-for="item in technicType" :key="item.name">// looping array
 <li v-show="hidden">{{item.name}}// show property
   <span><input type="checkbox" :value="item.name" v-model="checked"></span>
 </li>// checkbox
</ul>
<ul class="list" v-for="item in model" :key="item.name">// looping array
  <li>{{item.name}}// array item
    <span><input type="checkbox" :value="item.name" v-model="checked"></span>// checkbox
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list" v-for="item in technic" :key="item.name">//looping array
  <li>{{item.name}}// array item
    <span><input type="checkbox" :value="item.name" v-model="checked"></span>// checkbox
  </li>
</ul>

data(){
  return{
    technicType: [],//array i am getting from api
    hidden: true,
    model: [],//array i am getting from api
    technic: [],//array i am getting from api
    checked: []
   }
 }

 hideItem(id){
   this.hidden = id
 }
```

I need to hide the checked item. How could i implement this?

Comment: is this a component instance??? Also I feel this is bad practice to hide checked elements, if user makes a mistake and wants to uncheck element they won't be able to do that

Comment: This is the test task. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes if this is main vue instance I would attach `@click` on `<li>` element when and add `v-show` to list item as well. Also `item` should have ID attached to it as well so when your @click is called you can do something like `@click="hideItem(item.id)"` your function would look like the following `hideItem(id)` inside you would do something like get TechnicType.id == 5 and set it to hidden which would trigger your v-show. let me know if that was clear enough

Comment: I made some edits. I don't know how to use v-show properly. Would be grateful for any kind of hint

Comment: So v-show functions just like IF statement but it's used when you are toggling items instead of v-if which doesn't even render the element if false. So your v-show would look like this `v-show="item.hidden !== null" you can read up on it here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show

Comment: Have you tried something like `<input v-show="checked.includes(item.name)" ...>` ?

Comment: <input v-show="checked.includes(item.name)" ...> After adding this property its dont display elements.
`v-show="item.hidden !== null" How could i change v-show via handler? hideItem(id){
                this.hidden = id
            }

Comment: I implemented this via function filter, by passing id and slicing selected item by id

Answer (score 0):

First of all pay attention, you attach v-for directive to li tag, not to ul. Otherwise it will create multiple ul's instead of multiple li's.

Second, v-if and v-show are suitable in case of conditions only. For example in case you need to modify clicked item (by color, underlining, etc). But not suitable for removing forever.

Third, you do not need to create ID's manually for every item in your array. In v-for directive, besides item itself you can also pass its index, like so v-for="(item,index) in technicType". So when you'll be calling hideItem method you can pass index as an argument. @click = "hideItem(index)" so it will pass current item's index in your array.

And in the end in Vue instance you just splice your array like so

```
hideItem(index){
this.technicType.splice(index, 1);
}
```

It will delete item with index that you passed from html.